# I use django, postgresql, redis, channels, Docker tools for my project.I have some problem with Docker postgresql image

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, redis, channel

When I run `docker-compose up` command, this error occurs:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres_db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

**My docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    networks: 
      - redisnet

  postgres_db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  django_wsgi:
    container_name: django_wsgi
    build:
      context: .
    command: uwsgi --socket=:9000 --module=core.wsgi:application --py-autoreload=1
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks: 
      - webnet
      - redisnet
    links:
      - redis
      - postgres_db:postgres_db
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
  
  django_asgi:
    container_name: django_asgi
    build: .
    # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8002  core.asgi:application
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    networks: 
      - webnet
      - redisnet
    links:
      - redis
      - postgres_db:postgres_db
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
      
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.0
    depends_on:
      - django_asgi
      - django_wsgi
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static:/static
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"

networks: 
  webnet:
  redisnet:
```

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 
ENV REDIS_HOST "redis" 
RUN mkdir /code 
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip install psycopg2

COPY requirements.txt /code/ 
RUN pip install uwsgi 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
ADD . /code/
```

**My nginx default.conf file:**

```
upstream django_wsgi {
  server  django_wsgi:9000;
}

upstream django_asgi {
    server django_asgi:8002;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 80           default_server;
    root                /usr/src/app;
    index               index.html;
    client_max_body_size 60M;

    location / {
      include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass django_wsgi;

      uwsgi_param Host $host;
      uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    }

    location /chat/stream/ {
      proxy_pass http://django_asgi;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }
}
```

I think that for some reason my postgresql image is not visible - but this image is created, I can see it in Docker Desktop.

Comment: "my postgresql image is not visible". I assume you mean "container" not "image". Whatever try using "docker compose up" without any -d flag. Does that help? BTW docker-compose is now deprecated - you should install and use "docker compose" properly, https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you declared a network for the djangouwsgi service with:

```
networks: 
  - webnet
  - redisnet
```

This means that this container will only be able to contact the containers in the `webnet` or `redisnet` network.

On the other hand, you did not set any network for the `postgres_db` service, so this service is not able to comunicate with the services.

I will suggest adding a network to the postgres service and including the djangouwsgi under the same network.

Another option is to just remove all networks definitions, so all the containers inside of the compose file will be on the same network and they will be able to comunicate which each other.

Comment: I'd also recommend deleting _all_ of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.  `links:` are obsolete as well, and potentially problematic, and I'd also suggest deleting these.